# Dúvida com EntityFramework (Migration)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, wpf

Estou tentando fazer meu código rodar, mas não estou conseguindo por causa deste Error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error   CS0311  The type 'ControleInterno.Migrations.ControleInterno.ControleIntContexto' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'DbMigrationsConfiguration'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'ControleInterno.Migrations.ControleInterno.ControleIntContexto' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext'.   ControleInterno F:\Documentos\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Controle Interno\ControleInterno\Migrations\Configuration.cs  6

```
using ControleInterno.Model;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace ControleInterno
{
    class ControleIntContexto : DbContext
    {
        public ControleIntContexto()
        {
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }

        public DbSet<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Segue o código do arquivo Configuration.cs

```
namespace ControleInterno.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ControleInterno.ControleIntContexto>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(ControleInterno.ControleIntContexto context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
            //
            //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
            //      p => p.FullName,
            //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
            //    );
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Não entendo pq ele não reconhece minha classe de contexto...

Comment: Coloque o código da sua classe de contexto

Comment: Eu usei esta dica [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918401/enable-migrations-error-project-failed-to-build] e deu certo. Queria saber quais os efeitos disso?

Comment: Coloque também o código da classe de configuração que você excluiu. A explicação está nela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto aqui estava gerando ambiguidade de nomes:

```
namespace ControleInterno
{
    class ControleIntContexto : DbContext
    { ... }
}
```

Como você retirou o contexto do *namespace* correto dele (`ControleInterno.Models`), observe que o compilador resolveu o nome do contexto da seguinte forma:

```
ControleInterno.Migrations.ControleInterno.ControleIntContexto
```

E que obviamente está errado.

Bastava trocar o *namespace* do contexto e corrigir as referências que volta a funcionar.

Comment: Deu certo @CiganoMorrisonMendez . Por incrível que pareça, eu não modificado nada. Quando dei o Enable-Migrations ele já gerou assim.

Comment: Esse problema não é realmente simples. Percebi ele pela sua mensagem de erro.